# jQuery UI autocomplete is not a function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete in a MVC application but it won't autocomplete cause it can't find the function. I did however include the jquery-ui like this:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title Smoelenboek</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js")
</head>
```

however when i run the code like this:

```
 @Html.TextBox("parameter")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#parameter').autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Person")'
            });
        })
    </script>
```

it won't get to the method i've defined there here's the code for that method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
        {
            var items = new[] { "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Pineapple", "Peach" };

            var filteredItems = items.Where(
                item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
                );
            return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

it's just testdata but i don't get why it won't work. Perhaps duplicate imports or something?

Comment: Are you imcluding jQuery twice..?

Comment: it seems my problem was that i didn't add the bundle at the right place it had to be in the body not in the head. but thank you for your answer sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#parameter").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Person")",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 
            search: request.term,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.Id };
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sadly still the same error that he doesn't recognise the autocomplete function but thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe some will jelp this solution:

I figured out that the master page has a script manager which referes to the the

```
jquery.js
```

in

```
Scripts/external/jquery/jquery.js
```

This will lead to that one of the jquery variables becomes overwritten and your page is not able to recognize the function autocomplete.

What I did was to comment out the  reference to this file in my Site.master file:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <%--  <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" /> --%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```